# Copy range of files with same file structure

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to copy range of jpg files from the multiple folders.
I have a lot of folders with *.CR2 and *.xmp, in addition, it has a jpg folder with *.jpg files. I need to copy only jpg files and save file structure. 
example:

2018/folder1/jpg --> temp/folder1/jpg 
2018/folder2/jpg --> temp/folder2/jpg

Can this be automated? not to go to every folder and copy the files?
I tried Unix command:
cp folder1/*.jpg to folder1/jpg and got *.jpg: no such file or directory

Comment: Did my answer cover what you were trying to do? Did it work for you? Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to copy range of jpg files from the multiple folders. I
>   have a lot of folders with *.CR2 and *.xmp, in addition, it has a jpg
>   folder with *.jpg files. I need to copy only jpg files and save file
>   structure. example:
>
> 2018/folder1/jpg --> temp/folder1/jpg
>   2018/folder2/jpg --> temp/folder2/jpg

If I understand correctly what you're asking...

You can *change directory* into the `2018` *directory*, e.g.:

```
cd "/path/to/2018"
```

Then use, e.g.:

```
rsync -aR */jpg ../temp/
```

This will copy the `folder*/jpg` *directories* in `2018` to `temp` so you'll have `temp/folder*/jpg` *directories*, where `temp` it at the same level as the `2018` *directory*.

In other words, as in your examples:

> 2018/folder1/jpg --> temp/folder1/jpg
>     2018/folder2/jpg --> temp/folder2/jpg

They will be created as you've shown.

Answer (score -1):

You can try going to temp folder and typing

> `cp -R ../2018/folder*/*.jpg .`

and this should copy all jpg to temp but it won't copy folder1 to temp.

To copy folder1 and folder2 to temp again go to temp and type

> cp -R 2018/folder* .